# HTML: Cons and whats adverse about Illegal HTML (Why is it bad)?

Tags: html, standards, w3c-validation, web-standards

In a fully working website, with the looks and functions working just the way a client wants BUT loaded with tons of illegal HTML...what are the adverse effects of those illegal HTML?

My question might seem a bit simple, but I am trying to look beyond the obvious...Nowadays, web browsers ignore (or correct) illegal HTML. Is there a SEO penalty, or some other kind of problems besides slower loading time?

Comment: can you give an example of illegal html? And why you are using it? Nowadays, there are more and more people stuck on garbage browsers, like IE 6, and have no option for upgrading (like internal structures, municipalities, etc that do not allow users to install things) - so you cannot be sure they ALL render correctly

Answer (score 1):

Aside slower loading time, making fixes on such page by another developer/designer might take unnecessary long time for such person to understand the flow.

Also, come to think of a situation when you jQuery to 'backdoor' pick-up (or inject) some elements on (or into) your page, this can also lead to BIG bug.

There is no harm in proper planning of tag usuage and lots.

super!

Answer (score 1):

A big reason is to help you be sure that it will render correctly in different browsers and be understood correctly by other html readers, such as web crawlers.

Whilst HTML5 has increased specification for standardized error handling, that is still not going to guarantee that it will appear exactly the same to every browser, and there are increasingly too many browsers to test them all.

Also, good code is not just about validation but about semantic markup.  Letting search engines know what your content is by the correct use of markup can only help your site be understood correctly by the search engines, which is what SEO *should* be.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers will, as always, try to correct badly written HTML. The problem is that different browsers will "correct" the markup in different ways. Some may get it right, while others will fail in more or less subtle ways. Badly written HTML (and also CSS and Javascript) may result in:

- important content disappearing from the page,
- overlapping or unreadable content,
- forms that cannot be submitted,
- missing form elements,
- dead links and buttons,
- the author looking like an ass.